Go back to a safe-app after clicking `view transaction`
I'm working on a safe app for peanut-protocol. Everything is working as it should, but there is one annoying thing that I'm unsure on how to handle.
With peanut protocol you can create links that hold funds, that the recipient can claim to any wallet they like. We require the transaction hash that the safe apps sdk outputs after signing in your wallet, to create the link but it's easy for the user to lose the link. When submitting a transaction on safe, you will see the 'status screen', which gives the user the option to click on 'View transaction'. When you click on that, it navigates away and there is no way of going back to the app, which loses the funds.
Is there a way to return to the safe app without it reloading?

That sounds like it might just be too fragile a set up/solution.

Could you look at publicly storing something (ipfs) that can be used along with a signature to generate a url when needed or is there no verification/connection between the user going through the UX and any specific wallet?
If that is the case can you store some metadata publicly that can be used with a signature from a key that your protocol control and generate the targeted urls on demand that way?

You cannot store the state but in case you need more than one signature then a transaction footer (Transaction queue) will be showed if you are inside a Safe App. If you change to a different owner without refreshing then you can confirm the transaction without leaving the app

Think we're talking about something else. My issue is that its very easy for the user to close the safe app by clicking on the 'view transaction' button, which loses the state of the safe app and therefor loses the link that they tried to create.
